# Javascript library for dashboards - White label theme

Tags: javascript, extjs

We're looking for several Javascript library and came across '[White label theme'](http://themeforest.net/item/white-label-a-full-featured-admin-skin/270758).

Does somebody has experience with it and what is the feedback ?

We're mainly interested in the [layout](http://revaxarts-themes.com/?t=whitelabel) features for building dashboards. A nice look and feel, drag&drop and persistence is something we're looking for. JQuery support is something positive too.

Some experience with other libraries or something similar using extjs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify, you chose a theme on ThemeForest, not a JavaScript library. It has some JavaScript in it but its definitely not a library.

jQuery UI is the best because its well documented and you can modify the CSS to match your ThemeForest theme as you need via the Theme Roller.  Ext is awesome but its overkill and is costly and comes with too many strings attached. jQuery UI plays nicely with jQuery and John Resig (jQuery creator) is directly linking to it and endorsing it on the jQuery website.

To sum it up, jQuery is a bit lighter and doesn't have all the gazillion features ExtJS does. If you need tons of features, go with ExtJS. If you just want light and easy, go with jQuery UI.

By the way, that's a good name for an avatar.

Comment: Actually our need is a table layout (like ExtJS) with the nice features of 'ThemeForest" widgets (look, drag&drop, title...)

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of the mentioned theme.
Most UI JavaScript are from the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which works perfect in most cases. I've extended them to increase usability and to get drag 'n drop work on iOS devices.

If you just would like to have drag 'n drop feature (for instance) I really recommend the jQuery UI which is free and well documented with a strong community in the back.

My Layout is based on the [960 grid system](http://960.gs) in combination of the jQuery UI sortable plugin. I used a wrapper function to extend the functionality of course.

If you would like a light framework and get fast results you should go with jQuery if your application is going to be more complex I would prefer extJS

Comment: Hey cool! You are damn good at what you do. Oops I mean "Sie sind sehr gut."

Comment: Congratulation for the nice work (look is great). Ideally we need the functionalities of your widgets in a table layout. We haven't found anything, so if you have a couple of weeks free and want to work with a Swiss start-up we're always looking for black belt people ;-).

Comment: Thanks @icCube, unfortunately I'm not available for freelance work. You can purchase this template and use parts of it for your project. I don't think a table layout would work with these widgets though. I recommend to use div to create layouts since we have 2012 ;)

Comment: Bad luck for us. Yes, indeed for the divs, table layout was just using ExtJS terms.

Answer (score 3):

I can recommend ExtJs as a library of choice if you are comfortable with ExtJs [license](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/license/) and [pricing](http://www.sencha.com/store/extjs/) terms. They have excellent widget library, good documentation and stable API.

You don't need JQuery if you use EXtJs because ExtJs have DOM manipulation and helper methods.

I should also mention good community willing to help on their [forum page](http://www.sencha.com/forum/).

Only bad thing is maybe a bit slow start, you should give your self some time to get to know philosophy behind framework, their [class system](http://www.sencha.com/learn/sencha-class-system/) and [component model](http://www.sencha.com/learn/components/)

Comment: I already used ExtJs in a former project. Mainly, missing a layout with drag & drop features and an extended look & feel ability, it's very much to mimic a classical fat client UI ..

Comment: Ext have D'n'D built in, you can also override default behavior or write your own D'n'D to replace default. As for extended look and feel Ext provides you ability to write your own components, extend existing ones or override its CSS. They also have themes. So I'm not sure what specifically you need but I guess you can do it with ExtJs :) Of course in order to do it quickly and with good quality code you should be familiar enough with framework (that is bad thing about Ext I mentioned in my answer). Anyhow good luck with your project :)

Comment: The question is adding drag&drop to these examples : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html (on top of some persistence). Do you know of some examples of this?...

Comment: I wrote some examples how you can add D'n'D for ExtJs4 panels and window [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sbgoran/7LwvP/). I must say that I have more experience with older versions of ExtJs, but as a basic example on how to make panel "draggable" those examples should do just fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, thanks for the example. Actually our need is a table layout (like ExtJS) with the nice features of 'ThemeForest" widgets (look, drag&drop, title...).